# Checkin command in TFS is opening a Checkin window

Tags: command-line, tfs

I am trying to checkin and checkout items from TFS workspace using command line. I am able to checkout the folder `abc` using the command,

`tf checkout abc /recursive`

which is working fine. The problem arises when I use checkin command. The command I use to checkin is,

`tf checkin abc /recursive /comment:"Checkin check frmo CMD" /override:"Override"`

This opens a `Check In - Source Files` window in which I have to manually press `Check In` button and then manually press the `Override` button for TFS to checkin the files. How do I get rid of this manual intervention that is necessary to checkin the files?

Edit: You can find the screenshot of the window [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L0HJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `/noprompt` option in your command should do the trick.

> */noprompt*
>
> **Suppresses the display of windows and dialog boxes** (such as the Check In dialog box) and redirects output data to the command prompt.

More details please see this tutorial [use Team Foundation version control commands-Check In.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands)